# The arabic character changed to question marks after upgrade the php version from 5.6 to 7.2

Tags: mysql, wordpress, unicode, character, collation

I have a wordpress website when I tried to update the wordpress version to 5.4 it asks me to upgrade the PHP version. 
I did the upgrade from the server and when I back to the site before updating the wordpress I see all characters written in Arabic on my website changed to question marks. Then, I updated the wordpress to 5.4 and nothing changed. 
I checked the `wp-config.php` file and I found the charset set to utf8

```
/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
```

But the MySQL database set to

[image]

Also, I checked the web page header

```
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

Then, I added the following two lines in the `php.ini` file located in the `public_html` folder

```
default_charset = "UTF-8"
mbstring.internal_encoding = UTF-8
```

Below an image of the tags section for example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The connection parameters must agree with the encoding in the client.

Arabic cannot be correctly handled with latin1.

The question marks occurred during `INSERTing` the data; the data is lost.

For a list of causes of "question marks", see [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)